# average rows and columns across multiple data frames

Tags: r

New to R and learning the nuances of the language. I have the following function below for bootstrapping:

```
boot_fxn <- function (x, y){
x <- replicate(10000, mydata[sample(1:nrow(mydata), replace=T),], 
simplify=F) # number of bootstraps
y <- mvar_fxn # function to iterate over bootstrap samples
z <- data.frame(sapply(x, y)) #output of function
output <- t(z) #transpose the output
}

q <- boot_fxn(rep_data, mvar_fxn) # the function saved as an R object
```

print "q" gives the sample output below:

```
index   vars        w.1         w.2         w.3
X1      factor,7    Numeric,7   Numeric,7   Numeric,7
X2      factor,7    Numeric,7   Numeric,7   Numeric,7
X3      factor,7    Numeric,7   Numeric,7   Numeric,7
X4      factor,7    Numeric,7   Numeric,7   Numeric,7
X5      factor,7    Numeric,7   Numeric,7   Numeric,7
```

column 1: index of reps

column 2: where the 7 predictor variable names are stored

columns 3 to 5: where the coefs for each of 7 predictors are stored for the outcome (w1 to w3)

I can use the following code to see the data stored or (content) of each replicated sample:

```
data.frame(q[1, ]) # for the first indexed sample  

vars    w.1     w.2     w.3
V7      0.095   0.019   0.076
V10     0.054   0.022   0.096
V8      0.054   0.066   0.044
V5      0.032   0.088   0.039
V4      0.08    0.018   0.058
V9      0.021   0.103   0.022
V6      0.022   0.086   0.021

data.frame(q[2, ]) # for the second indexed sample, etc  

vars    w.1     w.2     w.3
V7      0.091   0.019   0.086
V10     0.051   0.022   0.098
V8      0.053   0.068   0.043
V4      0.08    0.017   0.059
V9      0.021   0.105   0.022
V5      0.03    0.073   0.042
V6      0.023   0.071   0.025
```

what I want to be able to do is the following

(a) find the average coef for each variable across each outcome for all reps, my desired output

will be like the below:

```
vars    w.1     w.2     w.3
V7      0.093   0.019   0.081
V10     0.053   0.022   0.097
V8      0.054   0.067   0.044
V4      0.056   0.053   0.049
V9      0.051   0.062   0.040
V5      0.026   0.088   0.032
V6      0.023   0.079   0.023
```

(b) a table of the confidence interval around these estimates.

```
vars    w.1LCL  w.1UCL  w.2LCL  w.2UCL  w3.LCL   w3.UCL
V4      0.093   0.119   0.081   0.112   0.093    0.119
V5      0.053   0.072   0.097   0.115   0.053    0.072
V6      0.054   0.067   0.044   0.078   0.054    0.067
V7      0.052   0.056   0.049   0.076   0.052    0.056
V8      0.051   0.062   0.040   0.082   0.051    0.062
V9      0.026   0.045   0.032   0.058   0.026    0.045
V10     0.023   0.048   0.023   0.045   0.023    0.048
```

I'm trying to find an efficient to go about doing the above.

Comment: you should edit your original post with the intended output instead of editing my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This unlists your list of matrix and converts it into an array.

```r
set.seed(2)
mat <- matrix(replicate(4, sample(4), simplify = F), ncol = 2)
mat
#>      [,1]      [,2]     
#> [1,] Integer,4 Integer,4
#> [2,] Integer,4 Integer,4
my_arr <- array(unlist(mat), dim = c(4, nrow(mat), ncol(mat)))
apply(my_arr, 3, rowMeans)
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]  2.5  3.5
#> [2,]  2.0  1.0
#> [3,]  2.5  3.5
#> [4,]  3.0  2.0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For question (b), you should start a new question or at the very least, create a reproducible example with an expected output.